# limit of sequence proof

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

This is an example problem in my book. The problem statement:

Prove lim$\frac{4n^3+3n}{n^3-6}=4$. I'm going to refer to the sequence elements by $a_n$ later.

(quick summary of the solution, I'm going to skip steps): Since we can't really isolate $n$ when we're trying to find $n=f(\epsilon)$, the author bounds $\frac{3n+24}{n^3-6}$ by $\frac{27n}{n^3/2}$. So it is true that $\frac{3n+24}{n^3-6} < \frac{27n}{n^3/2}$ for $n >2$. In the end, the author finds $n> \sqrt{54/\epsilon}$ and concludes that for every $\epsilon$, you should pick $n > $max$\{2, \sqrt{54/\epsilon}\}$ so that $|a_n - 4| < \epsilon$ is true.

I understand everything except for that last part. How do we know that for all $\epsilon > 54/4$, picking $n >2$ will work? This is saying that for large $\epsilon$, any sequence element past the second will be within $\epsilon$ distance of $4$. I just don't see how this is implicit right now.

I understand $n$ has to be greater than $2$ for the bound to work... I think I have a mental block.

Answer (score 1):

The important thing to realize is that once you have found an $n$ which works, *any* larger $n$ will also work. In order to find the bound $\frac{3n+24}{n^3-6} < \frac{27}{n^3/2}$ it was necessary to take $n>2$. By choosing $n > \max\{2, \sqrt{54/\epsilon}\}$, we always ensure that $n>2$ so that the bound holds, so that the proof works.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $\left|\frac{4n^3+3n}{n^3-6} - 4\right| = \left|\frac{(4n^3+3n)-4(n^3-6)}{n^3-6}\right| = \left|\frac{3n+24}{n^3-6}\right|$. Notice that $n^3/2=n^3-6$ implies $n^3=2n^3-12$ so that $n^3=12$. If $n \geq 3 >2$ then $n^3 \geq 12$. So this forces $n^3/2 < n^3-6$ [$n=12^{1/3}$ is the point where these curves pass each other]. Since $n^3/2$ is smaller than $n^3-6$ we get that $\frac{3n+24}{n^3-6} < \frac{3n+24}{n^3/2} \leq \frac{3n+24n}{n^3/2} = \frac{27n}{n^3/2} = \frac{54}{n^2}$.

So $\left|\frac{4n^3+3n}{n^3-6} - 4\right| < \frac{54}{n^2}$. If $n > \sqrt{\frac{54}{\epsilon}}$, one has that $n^2 > 54/\epsilon$ so that $\epsilon > 54/n^2$. This then implies that $\left|\frac{4n^3+3n}{n^3-6} - 4\right| < \frac{54}{n^2} < \epsilon$ whenever $n >\sqrt{\frac{54}{\epsilon}}$. Which finishes the proof (for every epsilon we've found an lower bound for $n$ to force the sequence and its limit to be within epsilon of each other).

Comment: So I understand $n > 2$ for the bound to work. I'm looking at the result and considering what happens when $\epsilon > 54/4$. The proof claims picking $n >2$ will work. But, right now, in my stupid state, I cannot understand which part of the proof justifies this. I feel it's being justified, but I'm not correctly understanding something.

Comment: @facepalm In the case where $\epsilon>54/4$, you can use the inequality in the last line of the first paragraph: $\frac{3n+24}{n^3-6}<\frac{54}{n^2}<\frac{54}{4}<\epsilon$.  (Keep in mind, also, that if you can find a value of N that works for a small value of $\epsilon$, then it will automatically work for any larger value of $\epsilon$, too.)

Answer (score 0):

The chosen $n$ is not necessarily just any $n$ that is greater than $2$. By definition of max, the chosen $n$ must also be greater than $\sqrt{54/\epsilon}$. This is how the author makes the proof work. As soon as $\sqrt{54/\epsilon} > 2$, then the chosen $n$ will be larger than $2$, and in general the chosen $n$ will become larger and larger as $\epsilon$ becomes smaller and smaller. This is what you need, suitably large $n$ for arbitrarily small $\epsilon$. It doesn't even matter what happens for large $\epsilon$, and the proof will still work. Admittedly, this seems to be a very clumsy way to prove such a limit, because there are much more direct methods to show that the limit is $4$.

Comment: If $\epsilon > 54/4$, then $n$ just has to be greater than $2$. I broke it up into two cases: when $\epsilon > 54/4$ and when $\epsilon < 54/4$. The first case confuses me.